# Can Blackboard use Oracle XE?

Tags: oraclexe

Can Blackboard Learn be installed on Oracle's Express Edition?

When running the Blackboard install script, it executes to completion and then spits out the message that Blackboard Learn was not installed, but doesn't give a specific reason.

Looking at the logs, it appears that Oracle is throwing the "ORA-25153: Temporary Tablespace is Empty" error, and what I think Blackboard is doing is installing the default schema, then patching the schema with the latest changes but the specific steps they're using may not work on XE.

I'm hoping for a "yes" or "no" sanity check before I spend a lot of time debugging the script, or alternatively, throwing out XE and installing 11g. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should tell us something about the OS environment you're trying to install on.
2. You should tell us what release and edition of Blackboard Learn you're talking about.
3. [Based on those facts](http://library.blackboard.com/ref/df5b20ed-ce8d-4428-a595-a0091b23dda3/Content/_admin_server_install/install_about_host_environment.htm), someone could look it up and learn if it's supported.

> For the exact versions of the databases that are supported, see "Supported Technologies" in the Release Notes for the release that you are installing.

From a quick sampling of some random releases, it doesn't look like XE is supported by any of them. 11g is supported (on Unix/Linux) by the latest release.

Comment: That was my impression as well. I was trying to set up a quick test environment using Blackboard Learn 9.1 on an Amazon EC2 instance running Amazon Linux and in the linked documents, it simply says that we need "an Oracle database." If your random sampling likewise implies XE is not supported, I can rule out the possibility I was looking at all the wrong sites.